# Catchable fatal error: Object of class player could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, methods

I am currently trying to learn some OOP by just doing it. I'm trying to create a small Roleplaying website using shops, items and a bank, but the only obstacle is this error getting in may way all the time and I don't know how to solve it myself. I've done some searching on the internets, but nothing came clear for me.

The script gives me

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class player could not be converted
>   to string

It tells me that is has to do something with the query within this bank method;

```
class bank {
     Function bankAccountBalance($player) {
       // getting account balance from player`s bank
      $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM player_bank WHERE player='".$player."'");
      while($balance = mysql_fetch_object($check)){return $balance->value;}
     }
}
```

and it is being used by this other method in another class

```
class shop {
     Function shopBuyItem($player,$item,$amount,$value) {
       // send item to player, remove value from bank
         $player = new player;
         $bank = new bank;
         $callback = new callback;
       $newvalue = $amount*$value; // calc total value of items
       if($bank->bankAccountBalance($player)>=$newValue)
       {
        // correct balance, trading the item
        $player->playerAddItem($player,$item,$amount);
        $bank->bankRemoveCash($player,$newValue);
       }
       else
       {
        // Incorrect Balance, abort
        $callback->errorMessage("Your bank account has insuffient balance. You cannot perform this transaction.");
       }
     }
}
```

I hope things are clear enough for everybody to help me solving this problem.
If you need any other code according to this topic to help me solve it, please ask me since I don't know what you exactly need.

Comment: Sidenote: No sense in using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions with OOP, it defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM player_bank WHERE player='".$player."'");`

Besides the unprotected query, `$player` is an object and you are treating it as a string, you're concatenating it with the rest of the string query.

Maybe you wanted to call some method, like `$player->getId()` or a public property, say `$player->id`?

Technically, you *could* convert an object to string (`json_encode()`, `serialize()`), or even implement out the magic method [__toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), but most likely that's not what you want to do in your current setup, right?

Comment: That worked, changed all the `$player` object vars to `$playerObj`